# Phpstorm Xdebug tunnel

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, ssh-tunnel

I have PHPSTORM, Xdebug and putty tunnel for 9001 port to listen Xdebug remote package.
Why Xdebug auto detect the return ip, like : -dxdebug.remote_host=91.***.***.152 , if I set localhost in *.ini file :
[image: {hpstorm configure]

And i also have this error in Xdebug.log:
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 91.***.***.152:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(

xdebug.ini:
[image]

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Maybe you are editing wrong php.ini file? 2) How do you debug -- CLI or web? If CLI -- how (screenshots etc)? 3) Show xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output obtained in a same way as you trying to debug.

Comment: Thank you for you response 
1) phpinfo() return correct changes
2)Phpstorm console

Comment: screenshots above. The problem is that Phpstorm don't stop on breakpoint.

Comment: 1) If you are debugging a CLI script .. why do you showing `phpinfo()` results gathered via browser? 2) Since you are debugging CLI ... do you use Remote PHP Interpreters?

Comment: Since it's not 100% clear on what you are trying to do here ... I will assume that you want to debug a CLI script on remote server. If so -- PhpStorm v8 supports Remote PHP Interpreters -- use them. 1) Create Deployment entry of SFTP type and configure it correctly (so that it has correct path mappings) 2) Define Remote PHP Interpreter using SSH details of that SFTP entry and mark it as Default interpreter for this project 3) Debug CLI script as usual -- IDE will create SSH connection for you and will execute it remotely

Comment: If you want to debug a remote CLI script that you cannot initiate from IDE (e.g. some cron task or some internal API call etc) then please refer to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7906 for additional info about how to provide server name and setup path mappings.

Comment: Few links, in case if you have not seen them yet: **1)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ **2)** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm **3)** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm **4)** (related) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm **5)** http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html

Comment: 2) Yes , i use remote PHP interpreters
I already use it (see sreenshot) above
I think it work fine, but one problem that Xdebug can't send me an answer to my localhost PC from remote server(
Thanks for links!